# Invalid SPF record

Tags: spf

I have the following SPF record:

```
v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net include:u3556354.wl.sendgrid.net ?all
```

I then sent an email to http://dkimvalidator.com but they gave me the error:

**Result: permerror (Included domain 'u3556354.wl.sendgrid.net' has no applicable sender policy)**

Full message is here:

```
Looking up TXT SPF record for thedealerapp.co.uk
Found the following namesevers for thedealerapp.co.uk: ns2.wixdns.net ns3.wixdns.net
Retrieved this SPF Record: zone updated 20170509 (TTL = 69760)
using authoritative server (ns2.wixdns.net) directly for SPF Check

Result: permerror (Included domain 'u3556354.wl.sendgrid.net' has no applicable sender policy)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it says: the hostname at `u3556354.wl.sendgrid.net` does not publish an SPF record. [Sendgrid's documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/spf.html) (which should have been the first place you looked) says you should use just plain `sendgrid.net`.

Having `?all` as your default action means that your SPF record is almost completely ineffective and will not do anything to prevent forgeries; you should use `~all` instead.

So your SPF record should be:

```
v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net include:sendgrid.net ~all
```

Comment: oh. I did read the docs here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Deliver/Sender_Authentication/spf_records_explained.html . So I am a bit confused on the different instructions?

Comment: The SPF include entry doesn't need to match your individual domain - you just want something that covers sendgrid's source IPs. Those docs are quite misleading - they are more about how SPF works in general, rather than specifically for sendgrid - the other ones I pointed at are better!